# EF 4.1 POCO mapping common table

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1

I have two "entity" tables: Provider and User. Both Provider and User can have multiple addresses (shipping, billing, etc.).

Rather then put address information in each entity table, I want to create a table that is common to both of them: An address table. I looked into creating, for instance, an address table with a primary key (identity column), entity type (provider or user), entity key (primary key of the parent entity table) and address type (shipping, etc.), along with the necessary address information.

One trouble I'm having is with foreign key constraints. If I have a foreign key from the parent entity table related to an address row, I found that I have a foreign key violation when I try to insert data.

I was thinking on removing the FK in the tables and then create on EF 4.1 the manual mapping but I dont know how can I do this:

http://i49.tinypic.com/2dt56dv.png (here is the image of the tables - objectid in address table holds userid or providerid and objecttype is a varchar that can be "USER" or "PROV")

How can I get around this? I'd like to use one table for addresses but I can't add a child for one parent without having a related row on the other parent. Of course, I'd like to keep using the foreign keys for referential integrity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is a pretty common scenario.

```
[Provider table]
ProviderID (PK)
AddressID

[User table]
UserID (PK)
AddressID

[Address table]
AddressID (PK)
Street1
Street2....
```

Go into provider table and add a FK from Provider.addressID to Address.AddressID

Go into Users table and add a FK from User.addressID to Address.AddressID

that should work and no FK's will be violated.

Comment: Losbear, your scenario is ok but this wont let me have multiple addressses for provider or for user right?